# Debugging Selenium crawling errors

Tags: selenium

I'm trying to crawl pictures using selenium, but I keep getting errors. What should I do?

Here's the syntax.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import urllib.request

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.google.co.kr/imghp?hl=ko&tab=wi&authuser=0&ogbl")
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
elem.send_keys("조코딩")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 1
# Get scroll height
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
while True:
    # Scroll down to bottom
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    # Wait to load page
    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)
    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".mye4qd").click()
        except:
            break
    last_height = new_height

images = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".rg_i.Q4LuWd")
count = 1
for image in images:
    try:
        image.click()
        time.sleep(2)
        imgUrl = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/c-wiz/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/c-wiz/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/a/img').get_attribute("src")
        opener=urllib.request.build_opener()
        opener.addheaders=[('User-Agent','Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1941.0 Safari/537.36')]
        urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
        opener=urllib.request.build_opener()
        opener.addheaders=[('User-Agent','Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1941.0 Safari/537.36')]
        urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(imgUrl, str(count) + ".jpg")
        count = count + 1
    except:
        pass

driver.close()
```

Below is the error syntax.

```
google.py:24: DeprecationWarning: find_element_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_element() instead
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".mye4qd").click()
google.py:29: DeprecationWarning: find_elements_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_elements() instead
  images = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".rg_i.Q4LuWd")
google.py:35: DeprecationWarning: find_element_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_element() instead
  imgUrl = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/c-wiz/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/c-wiz/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/a/img').get_attribute("src")
[1936:1984:0514/142442.544:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(999)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -200
```

I keep trying to change the syntax, but I get an error even if I keep doing it.
What should I do?

Comment: Did you try by using the new commands such as `driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".mye4qd")` instead of `driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".mye4qd")`? Note that you need to import `from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By` to use the new commands

Comment: Another error occurred when I did it that way.

Comment: google.py:36: DeprecationWarning: find_element_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_element() instead
  imgUrl = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/c-wiz/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/c-wiz/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/a/img').get_attribute("src")

Comment: Replace `driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/...')` by `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/...')`

Comment: show this error

Comment: [22012:9836:0514/230214.394:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [23:02:14.393] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1049 Failed to read descriptor from node 
connection: 시스템에 부착된 장치가 작동하지 않습니다. (0x1F)
google.py:30: DeprecationWarning: find_elements_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_elements() instead

Comment: DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:12236/devtools/browser/414c37ef-e39f-41cb-b417-48a67fd3dcf2
google.py:9: DeprecationWarning: find_element_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_element() instead
  elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")

Comment: Replace `driver.find_element_by_name("q")` with `driver.find_element(By.NAME, "q")`